# Method cannot be marked @objc because the type of the parameter 2 cannot be represented in Objective-C

Tags: swift, swift4, swift-protocols

I implemented a delegate in which all functions are optional, but I needed to make changes to one of the functions, namely add a second parameter, but I got this error **"Method cannot be marked @objc because the type of the parameter 2 cannot be represented in Objective-C"**. How can I fix this? Thank you.

```
@objc protocol ConversationDelegate: class {

    @objc optional func didUpdateConversation(_ conversation: ChatUserPersonalConversationModel, type: ChatGeneralManager.ConversationUpdateType) // **error here** 
    @objc optional func didDownloadedAllConversation()
    @objc optional func didDeleteConversation(_ conversationID: String)
    @objc optional func didDownloadNonFriend(_ nonFriend: RealmUser)

}
```

Comment: @the4kman Do you propose to make enum an heir from NSObject?

Comment: Make sure the enum is representable in Obj-C, that is, it inherits from `Int`.

Comment: @Sulthan thank you. It works.

Comment: @Alexander what type is `ChatGeneralManager.ConversationUpdateType` is it a class/struct or another protocol?